# How to insert in MYSQL different data for same ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table Photos with (product_id, description) like this
product_id 
1
1
1
2
2

I want to insert a description for the "first" product_id=1; another for the "second" product_id=1 etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any other fields on that table you have? and whats the initial value for description?

Comment: Little to go on here but I'd say there's something odd with the table structure. If multiple photos are linked to multiple products that would mean that an intermediary table should exist to link them up: photos <-> photos-products <-> products.

Comment: Is there a reason not to insert the entire row at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Shi stated, I would look into using a unique primary key.

Otherwise, if the entries are already populated you can use something similar to:

`UPDATE Photos SET description="DESCRIPTION" WHERE product_id=1 AND description="" LIMIT 1;`

This will add a description to the earliest entered row with matching ID and a blank description, assuming it's not indexed using a different column.

Comment: I agree. There should be at least a primary key for the photos table. This appears unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use a chaotic primary key, like an AUTO_INCREMENT value (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

This way, each record gets an own, unique identifier which you then can use to uniquely identify any given record.

Comment: Yes, i want to know if i can stop the insertion after each row

Comment: Well, yes. Once each record has a unique identifier, issuing an `UPDATE table SET description = "whatever" WHERE id = 1` will only match one single record.

Comment: That i understood. My question is : it is possible to stop the insert query after one value is inserted for each condition?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you run an `INSERT`, only one line (or as many as you gave) will be inserted. If you use an `UPDATE` which matches more than one row, you can use `LIMIT 1` to make it stop after one matched record, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stop the insertion after each row"?  It almost sounds like you want something like an [AFTER INSERT TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: I think what Bogdan S means is that INSERT (or UPDATE?) should only take effect on one row with a given product_id. Is that correct @Bogdan S?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a in `insert` query. Once your primary data has been inserted you use the [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function to grab the id of the newly inserted row. Then, using this new id you can use the `update` method to update any new data to the row you first created.

For example:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('mydb');
$variables = array (
    "one" => "something"
);

/* First query: */

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('" . $variables["one"] . "')");

$new_id = mysql_insert_id();

/* Data processes... */

$variable["two"] = "Something else";

/* Second query: */

mysql_query ("UPDATE mytable SET something = '" . $variable["two"] . "' WHERE id = '" . $new_id . "');
```

Comment: An alternative solution would be to add some constraints and do a INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Not sure if this actually helps the OP though (updating a description field with identical product_ids).

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** hard and fast rule that **forces** you to **use primary keys** in MySQL. You can and may create tables with no primary keys, and even with no keys or indexes, at all.

What you can define is this, with storage engine InnoDB:

```
CREATE TABLE photo_catalogue (
  product_id INT,
  description VARCHAR(128),
  INDEX(product_id, description)
) engine=InnoDB
```

Replace VARCHAR(128) by CHAR(128), if you want to use MyISAM tables. You can optionally define the index as `UNIQUE` though.

I have seen MySQL tables in production systems with millions of entries and no index, at all. On porpuse to avoid additional memory and performance issues with indexes.